# Work around to 255 column limit in SQL import export wizard for excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am trying to import an excel sheet to SQL database. This sheet has 700+ columns, but i understand there is a limit of 255 columns. Is there a work around to include all the columns while uploading to database. I selected Excel 2007 while selecting excel version.

Comment: You can have as many columns as you want.. it just might result in truncated values if you exceed a certain limit.

Comment: Consider a coding solution with Excel VBA making an ODBC/OLEDB call to SQL Server. No such limit should be imposed,

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, of the resources I saw online, there wasn’t an easy way to do this. I tried the above solution of choosing “Excel 2007” but that didn’t work for me. One would expect Excel and SQL Server to have tighter integration.

However, by converting to a .txt file and then working through some of the truncation errors, I managed to load my data set. Below is some detail of my use case and process.

I had a fairly small dataset row-wise (~200 rows) but with a large set of columns (+500 columns). I first converted the Excel file to a text, 'tab-delimited' file (i.e. *.txt). In loading through the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, I faced two truncation errors: one, a few of the column names were greater than 128 characters and two, the length of values in some of the rows where the default datatype was DT_STR was greater than 50 (the default output column width). For the first error, I just renamed the column(s) to something shorter. For the second error, I manually ran a count of lengths and found the maximum length of values for each column, which allowed me to isolate which columns would throw up an error. I followed the steps below:

1) In the SQL Server Import & Export Wizard 'General' Tab, I selected 'Flat File source' and accepted all the normal defaults.

2) In the second tab ('Columns'), ensure column delimiter is selected as Tab. I preferred this over a CSV format since there was some heavy text with commas in my dataset.

3) If the mapping works out, in the third tab ('Advanced'), you should get a laundry list of all your columns with their natural defaults. As detailed above, I isolated which columns had values that exceeded the default of DT_STR (50) and changed that to DT_TEXT.

4) The remaining steps just specify the destination, and whether you want to save the SSIS steps.

Comment: For item 3, in SQL Server 2012 there's a Suggest Types button on the Advanced page/tab. You can edit the number of lines to scan the entire file. It changed my long string columns to have a greater OutputColumnWidth (e.g. =1876), but kept them as DataType = DT_STR. It was writing to a column of type nvarchar(2000). The suggest option is much faster than trial an error to isolate values.

Answer (score -2):

A more simple, straightforward solution: on excel, sort your rows so the one with the longest value is moved to the top. It looks like the import wizard only looks into the first 8 rows of your data file to determine the width of each column (weird!).

source: [How does one change the default varchar 255 of a column when importing data from Excel to Sql Server using Import Export Wizard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433348/how-does-one-change-the-default-varchar-255-of-a-column-when-importing-data-from)