# OLEDB ignoring alpha-numeric values and returning NULL in excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, oledb

While reading data from Excel file using OleDbConnection, it is ignoring values of specific column having alpha-numeric values and returning NULL values. Issue is with only one specific column. Other alpha-numeric columns are working fine.

Below is the connection string I'm using

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ExcelFilePath;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"
```

**Tried below:**

- Removed IMEX=1 from conn. string but no use.
- Checked  registry `hkey_local_machine\software\Wow6432node\microsoft\jet\4.0\engines\excel` for option `Importmixedtypes`. It is set to `Text`.
- Changed HDR value to NO in conn. string. Now I am getting all results including alpha-numeric values.But it is not preferred because HDR=NO considers header columns names as data instead of headers.

Below code has been used for fetching data from Excel.
[image]

Comment: Issue usually occurs with first columns.  The JET/ACE looks at first column start at first row and if data is numeric thinks the first row is the Row Index instead of data.  Then gets confused and ignores alpha data in column 1.

Comment: Actually I am storing data in DataTable. When I check, dtExcelData values, alpha-numeric values of specific column , changed to NULL.Do I need to make any changes in Conn. string to resolve issue. I am getting issue at 4th column of excel.

Comment: The connection string looks ok.  Are you getting issues with or without the header row?

Comment: Looks like, as per article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448440/importing-from-excel-non-numeric-values-are-ignored  if the column first value is numeric, the engine will assume the entire column as numeric and when trying to convert a alpha value to numeric, it will fail. Changing specific column first value to alpha-numeric, resolved my issue.